# Change a file type's kind?

Tags: finder, spotlight

Files with the extensions .ts show up in finder as the kind "MPEG-2 Transport stream".   However I am developer and they are are actually text files, specifically TypeScript.

I tried changing the app associated with the files but that does not change the "kind".

Is there anyway I change the kind that MacOS associates with the extension .ts.   As when I use Spotlight and use "kind:movie".  All these text files show up.